# Nexus 6 on T-Mobile loses ability to send texts. Factory reset does not fix

Tags: cellular-radio, nexus-6, motorola-nexus-6

What is wrong with my mom's nexus 6. She was running stock Google Nexus software and kept encountering a problem where her texts would not send. I think I fixed it once by deleting the cache of some system apps (dialer service, messenger service) and restarting the device,  but I can't even be sure of that. I also tried a different default texting app.

It happened again last night so I spent a couple hours unlocking the Bootloader, installing twrp, and installing Cyanogen mod. While it works really well with cyanogen mod, she complained that the problem occured again after about 12 hours.

Does anyone here have insight into the likely cause of this? I reflashed recovery, so the only thing that remains is the bootloader.

Is it something with android 6.0, bootloader, baseband, or maybe something on Tmobile's end?

Comment: Got her running a custom recovery with cyanogen I think. It did not fix the problem. Perhaps the radio? But its just SMS...help